# Why was this useful question deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670770/how-do-i-check-if-the-window-is-in-fullscreen-in-swiftui-or-run-code-whenever-i) question which really helped me out. I later came back to upvote it, and it was deleted. Why was it deleted, and is there any chance it can be undeleted for my sake, and the sake of any SwiftUI developers who want to add a fullscreen button?

Screenshot of the deleted question
[image: screenshot of the deleted question]

Comment: it was closed, it entered the repoen queue, 3 people decided it should stay closed, and then the account that posted the question was deleted which resulted in the question being automatically deleted.

Comment: @KevinB I thought normally accounts being deleted doesn't cause their questions to be deleted, and I assume an account that posted useful questions probably wasn't "destroyed." Of course, without having 10k rep I can't actually see what happened to it.

Comment: @KevinB Why did it get closed in the first place? It looked like a fairly good/specific question to me.

Comment: Even at 10k rep, you can't see why an account was deleted.

Comment: @KevinB The question, I mean.

Comment: @JulianTiemann it was closed as off topic, in need of more info.

Comment: @KevinB I am not asking about the account's deletion

Comment: @KevinB It had plenty info

Comment: @JulianTiemann :shrug:? i don't know swift and can't judge the validity of the close reason, only that at least 3 people voted to close it, and at least 3 people voted to keep it that way.

Comment: The deletion is of course separate entirely, we don't know who the user was or why the account is deleted, but posts that are closed, downvoted, or in other words don't show any sign of being useful, do often get deleted with the account.

Comment: The question was deleted *because* the user account was deleted.  I think it is a new feature they didn't tell us about, seen it before.  When a user asks to delete their account then the machine automatically takes care of it, without an SO employee being involved.  Deletes their post as well, presumably (hopefully) limited to a single question.  That feature might have been added because there was a serious backlog in account deletions, people inside the company were re-assigned to different tasks and stuff didn't get taken care of.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery added screenshot of the latest version of the question. It has some...a bit amusing edit history. But basically, this is the most detail it had. Previous edits went at more length about why it shouldn't be downvoted or closed, rather than providing anything directly related to the problem.

Comment: Ah, now that I see the screenshot it makes sense. Honestly, that question doesn't deserve an upvote anyway.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery just for reference, the question does have two answers. They seem decent but I'm by no means an expert. One is by a user with 5k rep and it shows some Swift code that presumably does what the question asks. Another is by the question asker who self-answered based on the first solution was supplied. Also seems OK - it has some code and it's an actual answer, not just a misplaced edit or comment to the question. So, the question is sort of weak but the answers are OK-ish. I can provide screenshots if they answers should be relevant.

Comment: I can imagine a point at which people were voting to close the question/keep it closed when half the question was complaining ("Srysly tho, when I have to wait so long for an answer it ruins my day") instead of code. That's just not useful for anybody.

Comment: And don't forget the justification version https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59670770/4

Answer (score 5):

Whenever a user account is deleted, all of that user's negatively-scored posts are automatically deleted.

In this case, looking at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59670770/revisions) makes it quite obvious why the question was downvoted. The earlier revisions were little more than rants.

However, that problem can be easily corrected by editing. In the future, if you see a deleted post that you think should be undeleted, simply flag it for moderator attention.

If you are unable to view the post itself (*e.g.*, because you do not have the 10k+ privilege of viewing deleted questions), then choose one of your own posts (any will do) and flag it for moderator attention. Include a link to the other post and a brief explanation of why you think it should be undeleted by a moderator.

Comment: Well, consider it flagged.  What users don't know yet is why an upvoted answer got deleted as well.  That's new.  If you know anything about it from TL then please share.

Comment: um. I cannot flag it for undeletion as I am not a 10k mod

Comment: @JulianTiemann you should flag it for moderator attention with a short explanation.

Comment: @Julian With 15 rep, you can flag for mod attention. 10k is not necessary.

Comment: @L.F. for clarification, Julian (OP) couldn't flag it because it was in a state (deleted) that made the question not visible/available to low-rep users as well as users who did not answer the question.

Comment: @Samuel Hmm, that’s right. I missed that. OP can still flag an arbitrary post and include a link to the deleted question, though, right?